# Can not deploy a contract in a private clique " Not enough gas left for transaction"

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-deployment, gas, geth-clique

I have installed geth version 1.13.8.
Genesis block:

```
    {
      "config": {
        "chainId": 212121,
        "homesteadBlock": 0,
        "eip150Block": 0,
        "eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "eip155Block": 0,
        "eip158Block": 0,
        "byzantiumBlock": 0,
        "constantinopleBlock": 0,
        "petersburgBlock": 0,
        "istanbulBlock": 0,
      "muirGlacierBlock":0,
      "berlinBlock":0,
      "londonBlock":0,
      "mergeForkBlock":0,
      "mergeNetsplitBlock":0,
      "terminalTotalDifficulty":0,
      "terminalTotalDifficultyPassed":true,
        "clique": {
          "period": 0,
          "epoch": 30000
        }
      },
      "nonce": "0x0",
      "timestamp": "0x65b05c03",
      "extraData": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001cf8bbf32de2cb9b7c8e508c31d43ff87c007bc893011ae65fac09
    7e414c35f78f7fb4edccfa2077db506ed7c9df88b914f69f2504a6182ef0eb95a10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
      "gasLimit": "0x47b760",
      "difficulty": "0x1",
      "mixHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
      "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
      "alloc": {
        "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000": {
          "balance": "0x1"
        },
    .....
        "1cf8bbf32de2cb9b7c8e508c31d43ff87c007bc8": {
          "balance": "0x200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
        },
        "93011ae65fac097e414c35f78f7fb4edccfa2077": {
          "balance": "0x200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
        },
        "db506ed7c9df88b914f69f2504a6182ef0eb95a1": {
          "balance": "0x200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
        }
      },
      "number": "0x0",
      "gasUsed": "0x0",
      "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
      "baseFeePerGas": null
    }
```

When I try to deply a contract I get the gas left error. Can any one help me?
Thank you!

Comment: Does the account your are calling from have ETH ? Typically you should use one of the account that have a balance. I would set add the EOA you are signing with here

```
  
        },
        "93011ae65fac097e414c35f78f7fb4edccfa2077": {
          "balance": "0x200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
        },
        "db506ed7c9df88b914f69f2504a6182ef0eb95a1": {
          "balance": "0x200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
        }
````

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these flags to your node:

```
--mine --miner.gasprice 0 --miner.gaslimit 9000000000000000
```